# How do you determine the size of a composite data type?

Tags: java

```
public class Student {
    private int idNumber;
    private char[] firstName;
    private char[] lastName;
    private float gpa;
}
```

How would I determine the size of that composite data type?

I normally use `SIZE` but that only works on `Integer.SIZE` and such.

Comment: In Java it is complex.  Also it will depend on the JVM you use and its version.  Some info that may be useful: https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object

Comment: It's not straightforward to calculate it for a complex type. What are you going to do with the size once you have it? For example, do you want to know how much space it would take to serialize such an object to a file? Do you want to estimate memory usage for a large number of objects? Your use case will inform our answers.

Comment: Do you have access to this class file?  Could you just add a `getSize()` method to the `Student` class?  Otherwise, this gets much more complicated.  I recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object?) Q&A.